# How much memory calloc and malloc can allocate?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

How much memory `calloc` and `malloc` can allocate?

As `malloc` and `calloc` can allocate memory dynamically

Example

```
void *malloc (size_in_bytes);
```

And `calloc` can allocate memory depending on the number of blocks

Example

```
void *calloc (number_of_blocks, size_of_each_block_in_bytes);
```

Comment: It's system-dependent.

Comment: There are no restrictions other than you obviously cannot `malloc()` more bytes than the largest value `size_t` can hold. Ask for how much you want, and if it's too much, they'll both fail and tell you so.

Comment: @HotLicks yes its system dependent and I guess u r pointing towards the Heap concept

Comment: If you have to ask you cannot afford it.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from being limited by the amount RAM in the PC, it is system dependent, but on Windows, it's `_HEAP_MAXREQ` according to the [MSDN article on `malloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ewkz86d.aspx). Note though `malloc` and `calloc` are not guaranteed to allocate anything. It all depends on how much memory is available on the executing PC.

> malloc sets errno to ENOMEM if a memory allocation fails or if the amount of memory requested exceeds _HEAP_MAXREQ.

`_HEAP_MAXREQ` is defined as follows in `malloc.h` (at least in the Visual Studio 2010 includes).

```
#ifdef  _WIN64
#define _HEAP_MAXREQ    0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE0
#else
#define _HEAP_MAXREQ    0xFFFFFFE0
#endif
```

You shouldn't really worry about this though. When using `malloc` you should decide how much memory you really need, and call it with that as the request. If the system cannot provide it, `malloc` will return `NULL`. After you make your call to `malloc` you should **always** check to see that it's not `NULL`. Here is the C example from the MSDN article on proper usage. Also note that once you've finished with the memory, you need to call `free`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // For _MAX_PATH definition
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main( void )
{
   char *string;

   // Allocate space for a path name
   string = malloc( _MAX_PATH );

   // In a C++ file, explicitly cast malloc's return.  For example, 
   // string = (char *)malloc( _MAX_PATH );

   if( string == NULL )
      printf( "Insufficient memory available\n" );
   else
   {
      printf( "Memory space allocated for path name\n" );
      free( string );
      printf( "Memory freed\n" );
   }
}
```

Comment: But knowing that isn't likely to be helpful; you can't necessarily allocated `_HEAP_MAXREQ` bytes if the system doesn't happen to have that much available. Call `malloc()` for what you need and check whether it succeeded.

Comment: @KeithThompson, the OP asked what the limit was, and that is the question I answered. I in no way suggested that it was a good idea to call it with `_HEAP_MAXREQ` as you seem to be implying.

Comment: Well, if you look at the numbers, that's the entire address space minus 32 bytes. That's hardly the practical limit, even on 32 bit systems.

Comment: No, that's not what I was implying, nor am I suggesting that your answer is bad. My point is that knowing `malloc` can't allocate more than `_HEAP_MAXREQ` bytes isn't likely to be all that useful. What's useful is knowing whether it's able to allocate what your program needs right now, and that's determined by whether it returns a non-null pointer. My comment is aimed more at the OP's implicit assumptions than at your answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson, no argument from me on whether it's useful or not. You're at the mercy of the OS regardless of what of `_HEAP_MAXREQ` is defined as. I'll modify my answer to mention proper usage of `malloc`.

Comment: Windows with PAE enabled alters this situation.  However, I don't remember how it alters it. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can allocate as much bytes as type `size_t` has different values. So in 32-bit application it is 4GB in 64-bit 16 *I don't even know how to call that size*

All in all you can allocate all memory of machine.

Comment: Just for giggles, I looked it up. Apparently it's 18.4 quintillion bytes, on the short scale, or 18.4 exabytes.

Comment: There's no such guarantee in C. `size_t` would be larger or smaller than the address space. The actual limit is 2 to the power of `(CHAR_BIT * sizeof(void *))`.

Comment: @Paul, oh it is exabytes, but not 18.4. It just looks in decimal expression like 18.4.

Comment: @ST3: Exabytes are decimal quantities, exbibytes are their binary cousins.

Comment: No, `SIZE_MAX` is a restriction for `malloc` and its square for `calloc`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the language definition is concerned, the only upper limit per call is what `size_t` will support (e.g., if the max `size_t` value is 2<sup>32</sup>-1, then that's the largest number of bytes `malloc` can allocate for a single block).

Whether you have the resources available for such a call to succeed depends on the implementation and the underyling system.

Comment: This is wrong for the same reason I commented on ST3's answer.

Comment: @R: Chapter and verse, please.

Comment: There's no citation because nowhere in the C standard does it say the total amount of memory you can obtain is bounded by the maximum value that fits in `size_t`. The type `size_t` is merely the type for the result of `sizeof` that should be able to represent the size of any single object. There are pathological implementations where `size_t` is smaller than the total size you can allocate, e.g. 16-bit `size_t` and "far" pointers on certain 8086/DOS memory models.

Answer (score 0):

On linux, indefinite amounts, i. e. much more than you have either physical or virtual memory.

As long, as you don't actually use it, you're fine, it's just when you actually use more memory than available that the out-of-memory killer starts running amok, and shoots down your process.

This is the reason why many people don't bother checking the result of `malloc()` anymore, because it's not null even when the returned buffer can never be backed...

Comment: What about other flavours of OS?

Comment: Sorry, I don't use nonfree systems, so I can't say too much about them.

Comment: Although I don't think it will let a single process allocate more memory than it has virtual address space for, i.e. if you're on a 32 bit system, it won't allocate you much more than 4GB.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Yes, on a 32 bit system, you have the restriction of the address space, which restricts you more than just the 4 GB limit you mentioned. On a 64 bit system, a single process is really able to allocate more memory than the virtual memory limit allows, this is called "memory overcommitment": if you have 8 GB RAM + 8 GB virtual memory, a process is able to allocate 17 GB.

Comment: @cmaster: I think it's the same principle, but obviously 64 bits can address a whole lot more than 17GB. Not my area of expertise, but if I remember right I think Linux artificially limits it to 2^50 on a 64 bit machine, or something similar.

Comment: Keep in mind that with some architectures it may be impossible to allocate something larger than a certain amount (eg, 4GB minus some delta) as a contiguous piece, or at least it may be unpredictable whether it will be available or not.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Yeah, probably you're right... for some reason I generally forget about the theoretical limits in favour of the practical ones, it's only when a theoretical limit becomes practically achievable that I take interest in it. Call me too pragmatic, if you like, but I've given the limit that I believe is actually important.

Comment: This answer is definitely wrong: you can never allocate more than virtual memory. In order to do so, `malloc` would have to return pointers to overlapping regions, which is not permitted by the C language. You *may* be able to allocate more than physical memory; whether you can depends on the system configuration.

Comment: @R. Sorry, to contradict you, but you are wrong. The point about virtual memory is, that `malloc()` only has to return a point in the virtual address space, and that the kernel has to know, how to react, should a page fault occur within the malloc'ed region (i. e. actually put a memory page behind the virtual addresses). There does not have to be any memory page available for that when `malloc()` returns. Empty pages don't need to be backed by virtual memory space.

Comment: @cmaster: OK, your problem is that you have your definitions of virtual and physical memory backwards...

Comment: @R.. Here is a good link for you, if you don't believe me: http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html Under the header "Overcommit and OOM", you find example codes that do precisely what I described.

Comment: The very first line of the document you linked to defines "virtual memory" as "address space", supporting my original comment. All I can figure is that you're using "virtual memory" to mean the combination of physical RAM and other types of physical memory (like swap), aka the traditional Windows misuse of the phrase "virtual memory". Otherwise what you're saying is nonsensical.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39217/discussion-between-cmaster-and-r)

Answer (score 0):

1) It depends on the resource limits of the user. 
2) It also depends on the availability of address space.