# Taking large character array as input in c

Tags: c

I want to take a large character array as input.
E.g.: `char array[c][d]`
where `c <= 200000` and `d <= 500000`.

Is there any way in C programming language to take such a character array as input?

Comment: X-Y problem. ..

Comment: Why such a large array you require? May be possible on a 64-bit system but you'd need to use `malloc` or `calloc`. This question will be of interest to you: [How much memory calloc and malloc can allocate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367881/how-much-memory-calloc-and-malloc-can-allocate)

Comment: Yes,just use the code for a small array as input but with bigger limits...

Comment: can you show us what you have tried and the problem you  faced.

Comment: Why would you even want to take it as an input? Usually large arrays of data are read from files.

Comment: I am new in programming. I am trying solve a program in which test cases can have input strings  up to 200000 and each can have length of 500000. So I am trying to store them in a character array.

Comment: So... are you sure you need to store all of these *in the same time*? I really doubt it. Each test case is processed in it's own turn.

Answer (score 0):

After declaring an array, you can use [`calloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/calloc/) function in order to give size to your array. So your code will approximately look like this:

```
char** array;
array = calloc(c, sizeof(char*));
```

And there is no need, for defining second value, as it will change autimatically. But if you still want, you can write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    array[i] = calloc(d, sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 0):

> Taking large size character array as input in c ...
>    Is there any way in C programming language to take input such a character array?

If code *truly* needs to retain all c <= 200000 test cases at once ...

Yes, read in each *line*, one at a time and then allocate per its length.  There is certainly little need for a `char array[200000][500000]` array.  Use an array of `char *` pointers instead.

```
#define c_MAX  200000
#define d_MAX  500000

// Allocate pointer array and a single buffer for reading the lines
char **array = malloc(sizeof *array * c_MAX); 
if (array == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof *buffer * (d_MAX + 3));  // Add room for 1 extra, \n, \0
if (buffer == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();

size_t c_count = 0;
while (fgets(buffer, d_MAX + 3, stdin)) {
  if (c_count >= c_MAX) Handle_too_many_lines();
  size_t len = strlen(buffer);

  // lop off potential \n
  if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n') {  // lop off potential \n
    buffer[--len] = '\0';
  }
  if (len > d_MAX) Handle_too_long_a_line();

  // Make a copy 
  size_t sz = sizeof array[c_count][0] * (len + 1);
  array[c_count] = malloc(sz);
  if (array[c_count] == NULL) Handle_OutOfMemory();
  memcpy(array[c_count], buffer, sz);
  c_count++;
}
free(buffer);

// TBD code
// Right-size `array` if desired with realloc()

// Use the `c_count` elements of `array`

// when done free them all
for (size_t i = 0; i< c_count; i++) {
  free(array[c_count]);
}
free(array);
```